# Invalid win32 Application Visual Studio Application

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I created an application in Visual Studio using VB.Net and service-based database. But when I run it on another computer, it gives an eror:

> Invalid Win32 Application

It runs fine on my own computer in which I created it.

Please hellp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether .Net Framework is installed in the target computer because you should have the .net framework installed in the computer in which you want to run your application.

Comment: How did you run it on the second computer?

Comment: I Build It In Visual Studio . And Copy The File From My Project's Bin Folder
C:\Users\Zia\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Directory\Directory\bin\Debug

Comment: I build It on Visual Studio and Copy file Form Bin Folder

Comment: Based on this, I cannot give you a solution. But a small workaround, try to copy the complete Debug folder and then it should work.